# Microscopy Book Suggestions

Tags: cell-biology, literature, book-recommendation, microscopy, imaging

I've learned programming through great book recommendations; many from the Stack Exchange series of sites. I'm hoping to take this approach in order to gain a fundamental understanding of how fluorescence microscopy and sub-diffraction limit imaging tools work.

What books or reviews do you recommend that offer both a conceptual explanation of imaging biological specimens and practical advice? I'd settle for either one if you find the author to be effective.

Comment: Would also like to see a good reference!  ejstrong, would you be looking at cells, microorganisms, subcellular processes?  might be useful to you to be particular.  the game gets very different between butterfly wings and organelles.

Comment: Recommendation questions normally end up soliciting lists.  You've narrowed down your your focus a little bit, but there are still scores of books on microscopy out there.  Can you narrow it down any further (as shigeta alluded to)?

Comment: I am going to leave this as a comment, because I don't think this is exactly what you need, but the Cold Spring Harbor books about imaging are very good if you are going to use the techniques in the lab (they're very much focussed on practical issues). I own [Imaging in Neuroscience: a laboratory manual](http://goo.gl/u1usc) but you can also find [a book on imaging in general](http://goo.gl/1RlHi), one on [live cell imaging](http://goo.gl/VIQNJ), and one on [developmental biology](http://goo.gl/fm8ve).

Comment: @Shigeta - sorry for not specifying. I would be looking at both cells and organotypic culture.

Comment: @jonsca - I would first want to learn about imaging live cells but would appreciate an overview of fluorescence imaging in addition to learning about specific imaging applications.

Comment: Apart from/ along with books, one can also learn through this course on [ibiology][ https://www.ibiology.org/online-biology-courses/microscopy-series/]